# Open Sans installed by default on all major OS's

Tags: fonts

Do all major operating systems have Open Sans installed by default? Ie, if my website uses Open Sans will it display on:

- Windows
- Mac OS
- Linux
- iOS
- Android

Answer (score 7):

No, in fact if you instal open sans then the font variants on graphic design stackexhange stop working. But no Open Sans is not part of Windows, Mac or IOS defaults.

But does it matter? You can just specify it as a webfont and then it will show up regardless of it being installed or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What do you mean a webfont. Do you mean include it via Google Fonts then in css specify as a webfont?

Comment: @JakeM that is one way. Or you can host the fonts yourself too